# Unhandeled exeception catch block of c++

Tags: c++

```
try{
    throw ;
}
catch(CException *pEx){
   CString sample=(_T("IIII")); //   Why cant i initialize CString variable?
//Unhandeled exception during run time  When i am throw,
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`throw;` rethrows the currently handled exception. This form is only allowed when an exception is presently being handled (it calls `std::terminate` if used otherwise). See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw for yourself.

So, basically, your program terminates at `throw ;`.